# Mysql select date from different table

Tags: php, mysql

hye guys i'v a problem with selecting a date from another table. 
basically i have tables like

```
 1) users table, 
 2)follow table, 
 3) photos table, etc.
```

i'm trying to select the **date** from photos , but its not working. 
Here is my mysql query. Here I'm selecting the **followers** from the follow table where the **follower = the user_id**

**followers_photo.php**

```
$the_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$getuser'"); 
$tuser=mysql_fetch_array($the_user); 
$isuser = mysql_num_rows($the_user); 

$tu_id = $tuser['id']; 
////users whos following Me 
$followers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE followers ='$tu_id' order by id desc"); 
$f_s_count = mysql_num_rows($followers);
```

and here I'm retrieving the photos base on their **date and the following id**.

**index.php**

```
include('func/followers_photos.php');
       if($f_s_count > '0')
           { 
        while($uim = mysql_fetch_assoc($followers)){ 
        $i_id = $uim['following']; 
           $followers_image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = '$i_id' order by date"); 
        $disimg = $fimage['img'];
        $disid = $fimage['id'];
        $distime = $fimage['date'];
        $i_like=$fimage['likes'];
        //$i_unlike=$fimage['down'];
        $likes_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voting_ip  WHERE mes_id_fk = '$disid'");
        $ipadd = mysql_fetch_assoc($likes_ip);
        $check_likes= $ipadd['mes_id_fk'];
        $user_follow_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$i_id'");
        $ufde = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_follow_details);
        $uiname = $ufde['username'];
        $uinim = $ufde['img'];
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

ending brackets are after the html code.

above code works but i can't manage to sort the photos base on their date because i'm selecting data from the table base on the id.

here is what i tried so far.

```
$the_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$getuser'"); 
$tuser=mysql_fetch_array($the_user); 
$isuser = mysql_num_rows($the_user); 

$tu_id = $tuser['id']; 
////users whos following Me 
$followers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow,photos WHERE followers = photos.user_id order by photos.date desc"); 
$f_s_count = mysql_num_rows($followers);
```

above code will work but will select all the photos from the database and not from the the following id. what i mean is even the user i don't follow their picture will show.

what i'm trying to accomplish is select from who i follow and sort their photos by the photo date which is stored in photos table. i'm really stuck , anyone could help me out ? your replies are appreciated. sorry for my bad english.

### EDIT

now this works as i want but it shows the images multiple times.

```
$followers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow,photos WHERE photos.user_id = '$tu_id' and follow.followers = photos.user_id order by photos.date desc");
```

### Another Edit

now with this it doesn't display the images multiple times but whenever i post a new image it wont be at the top its still sort them base on the ID. 
just a little modification on @GonGordon Linoff suggestion

```
SELECT distinct follow.*
FROM photos join
     follow
     on  follow.followers = photos.user_id
WHERE    photos.user_id = $tu_id
order by photos.date desc;
```

Comment: I don't understand the comment on you "another edit".  If you add a new photo, it should have the most recent date, so it should appear at the top.

Comment: it doesn't i guess its still sort them base on following $i_id in index.php. SELECT * FROM photos WHERE user_id = '$i_id' order by date
because if i did put your code in followers.photo.php then the $i_id is undefined in index.php since you are selecting the photo.* i reverse your code and no duplicates but however it still order the images base on the $i_id.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
$followers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow, photos 
WHERE follow.followers = photos.user_id and photos.user_id = '$i_id' 
order by photos.date desc");
```

Comment: i did this five minutes ago and it display the same image multiple times

Comment: If there are more then one followers of one user id then it will return same user multiple times. I suggest, you check how many rows are returned by this query after which we can restrict the result with the help of "Limit 1" in query.

Answer (score 0):

Your final query is on the right track.  You just need to add in the condition on which user:

```
SELECT * 
FROM follow join
     photos
     on follow.followers = photos.user_id
WHERE photos.user_id = $the_user
order by photos.date desc;
```

EDIT:

If you want to get all photos that a given user is following, then I did the logic backwards:

```
SELECT distinct photos.*
FROM follow join
     photos
     on follow.followers = photos.user_id
WHERE follow.user_id = $the_user
order by photos.date desc;
```

Comment: nope it did not. and actually it displays the same image multiple times.

Comment: @user2660611 . . . Do you have duplicates in the tables?

Comment: yeah. because the user follow himself automatically when singin. privacy stuff. does it matter ? if so could u guide me :)

Comment: wait a second i'll delete the duplicates and see :)
Edit: even after deleted the duplicate it still duplicate the image

Comment: @user2660611 . . . In that case, just use `select distinct photos.*`.

Comment: i'v deleted the duplicates from follow table. and used your above code and it still loop the same image multiple times. do i edit my question and post the other long code that i'm using to display the photos as in my code above ? or just i email them to you. your choice and thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @user2660611 . . . Edit your question